# UIImageView returns to the original position while animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'm trying to make an animation for my app. I want to move my image to the center of the `UIView`(my background for the animation) and then change the height of that `UIView`(my background), and at that moment the problem occurs - my image goes to the original position. Here's my code:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            animationView.alpha = 1
        }) { (true) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
                infoImage.center.x = animationView.center.x
            }) { (true) in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.5, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
                    animationView.frame = CGRect(x: 8, y: cellFrame.minY, width: cellFrame.width - 16, height: cellFrame.height + 200)
                }) { (true) in
                    print("completed")
                }
            }
        }
```

The first block of animation just makes it visible. The second block of that animation moves the image to the center. The third block increases the height of `UIVIew`.
Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I suppose you already know this, but the problem is `animationView.frame = CGRect(x: 8, y: cellFrame.minY, width: cellFrame.width - 16, height: cellFrame.height + 200)`. It’s all about what `cellFrame` is

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are overriding the x value.

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
        animationView.alpha = 1
    }) { (true) in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            infoImage.center.x = animationView.center.x
        }) { (true) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.5, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
                animationView.frame = CGRect(x: animationView.center.x, y: cellFrame.minY, width: cellFrame.width - 16, height: cellFrame.height + 200)
            }) { (true) in
                print("completed")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Then how can I change the height value?

Comment: `animationView.frame.size.height` produces the same bug